# I keep getting Array to string conversion error using json_decode

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to convert a Json string in php pulled from my mySQL database. I've been successful with other strings like this using json_decode,  but for some reason when I try decoding this string:

```
$Json ='{"S1": "15,2,0,4,0,0,1","S2": "50,0,99,1,5,1,1,0"}';

json_decode($Json, true);
```

I get the error 'Array to string conversion'.

I've been doing the same thing successfully with this string,

```
[{"group":"new","users":",12345678","S1":"56,3,0,0,0,6,0","S2":"0,0,49,0,4,0,0,0","enabled":"1","admin":"1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0"}]
```

I don't know what the differences between the two are, as they both are pulled from the same database, and both validate as Json successfully.  Can someone tell me how I can successfully convert this so that I can get json_decode to work on it successfully? Thanks.

**update: Here's the actual code I'm using

```
$tmpUserJson = $row['JSONSettings’];    

$tmpUserJson='['.$tmpUserJson.']'; ///I’ve tried with and without brackets    

echo $tmpUserJson; //returns {"S1":"15,2,0,4,0,0,1","S2":"50,0,99,1,5,1,1,0”}    

$userJson = json_decode( $tmpUserJson , true);    

echo $userJson['S1']; // returns Notice: Array to string conversion
```

Comment: `[]` makes an array. I've never seen the `{}` used for shorthand array construction but looks like it does the same thing.

Comment: I don't get this error, if I execute your code - are you sure, you post the code, which throws the error?

Comment: i tried the exact string but getting result without error... all i can think is mysql_escape_string just check if the string posted is exact what the output is from mysql... or the double quotes are escaped...

Comment: Couldn't put code in the comments, so I added to the question.

Comment: It was happening because I had originally been trying to echo the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get it because you are trying to echo out an array. 
Try:

```
$Json ='{"S1": "15,2,0,4,0,0,1","S2": "50,0,99,1,5,1,1,0"}';

$Json = json_decode($Json);

foreach( $Json as $item ){
    echo $item. "<br />";
}
```

Or you can var_dump your results:
    $Json ='{"S1": "15,2,0,4,0,0,1","S2": "50,0,99,1,5,1,1,0"}';

```
$Json = json_decode($Json);

var_dump($Json);
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$userJson = json_decode( $tmpUserJson , true);// this line return an associative array    

echo $userJson; // echo can't echo out an array that's why you got that error
```

As @David mentioned, if you want to echo out `$userJson` then you have couple of options:
**1: loop through the array elements** e.g : `foreach($userJson as $value){ echo $value;}`
**2 for testing purpose** : you can view `$userJson` data by using `var_dump($userJson)` or `print_r($userJson)`;
Good luck